# Scrapy - get content after an identified class

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the content from this html:

```
<div class=product_detail>
  <p>
    Random stuff
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="brand_color">Brand:</span>Product Brand
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm able to get "Brand:" with `response.css('span.brand_color::text')`, but i'm not able to get "Product Brand".

I'd like to build something that:

1. find the brand_color span --> This is not present 100% of the cases
2. Go up, to find the father
3. Then go down, ignore somehow the span, then select the ::text.

(my logic may be completely wring though).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the BeautifulSoup. It's a very strong parsing library.

Read More about BeautifulSoup here: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You can install it easily:
`pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
HTML = '<div class=product_detail> <p> Random stuff </p> <p> <span class="brand_color">Brand:</span>Product Brand </p> </div>'

parsed_object = BeautifulSoup(HTML)
res = [p.get_text().strip() for p in parsed_object.find_all('p')]
print(res)
```

You'd get the following content:

```
['Random stuff', 'Brand:Product Brand']
```

You can then use the `split` to extract your data

```
brand_name, paragraph_content = res[1].split(':')
print(brand_name)        # Brand
print(paragraph_content) # Product Brand
```